# The Obligatory "Post Your Rig" thread...

Tags: production-mixing, gear, deva, lectrosonics, macgyver

I'm in production audio.  I do a lot of sound effects recording and production sound mixing.  As you probably know, this is a very small industry.  Because of this, I can't ever get enough of seeing other people's rigs.  The other thing that it leads to - and this is my favorite part - is that there's often something that you want to do on your rig that either involves a piece of gear that doesn't exist or isn't meant to run off 12V dc power, or involves a piece of gear that you can't possibly afford, which in turn leads to a significant amount of "MacGuyvering" and custom jobs.

I think this would be an awesome place to share pictures of rigs and pictures of custom jobs and such.

Here's a pic from a TV pilot I worked on recently:

[Deva Mix 12 Rig http://colinhartonline.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/afmset.png](http://colinhartonline.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/afmset.png)

Comment: I'm tempted to create a "MacGyver" tag now.

Comment: Good Idea!  I'm constantly giving MacGyver a run for his money...

Comment: + 11 for Mark C for bringing up MacGyver ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I can post a picture tomorrow but my basic kit includes a [Sound Devices 442](https://web.archive.org/web/20190224102043/http://www.sounddevices.com:80/products/442master.htm), [Sound Devices 744T](https://web.archive.org/web/20120506012634/http://www.sounddevices.com/products/744t.htm), [Sanken CS-3e](https://www.sanken-mic.com/en/product/product.cfm/8.1001500), [Rycote blimp and windjammer](http://79.170.44.127/rycote.com/products/full_windshield_kit/), [Sennheiser 2000](https://web.archive.org/web/20121121005504/http://www.sennheiser.co.uk:80/uk/home_en.nsf/root/professional_wireless-microphone-systems_broadcast-eng-film_2000-series) wireless units with [Sanken COS-11's](https://www.sanken-mic.com/en/product/product.cfm/5.1107000), a small [Audio Technica](https://web.archive.org/web/20160331195313/http://eu.audio-technica.com:80/en/products/category.asp?catID=2) condenser mic, I forget which model number, and a ton of accessories to put the mics nearly anywhere, anytime.  I'll be adding a stereo mic setup very soon and also a [Midas Venice 160](https://web.archive.org/web/20130509070751/http://www.midasconsoles.com:80/venice.php) as a cart mixer.

[image: Midas Venice 160]
<sub>(source: [10outof10.co.uk](http://www.10outof10.co.uk/acatalog/venice160.jpg))</sub>